# Can I add a WindowListener to a MenuItem?

Tags: java, awt, frame, menuitem, windowlistener

I have a program written in AWT, so I am using Frame (Not JFrame/Swing).
I am using MenuItem objects to do some operations through ActionListeners.

However, on my last MenuItem, I want to use a WindowListener to close the frame (intending to close the frame without terminating the program altogether).

I am aware that the MenuItem documentation doesn't have a addWindowListener() method. But is there a way around that?

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    f.dispose();
}});
```

This is pretty much what I'm trying to do, but from a MenuItem.

Comment: *"I have a program written in AWT"*  I had some of those as well, ..last millennium.  Why do you ***still*** have them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window listener is not about *making* the window close - it's a set of callbacks that happen when a window does particular things.  From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html):

> When the window's status changes by virtue of being opened, closed, activated or deactivated, iconified or deiconified, the relevant method in the listener object is invoked, and the WindowEvent is passed to it.

`windowClosing` has the following Javadoc:

> **`void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)`** 
>   Invoked when the user attempts to close the window from the window's system menu.

If you want to programatically close the window when someone clicks the menu item, then simply add an action listener with the following:

```
f.setVisible(false);
f.dispose();
```

Comment: That makes more sense. I was confused! Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE: oops, that should be `setVisible(false)` rather than `close()` - answer has been edited.